# heroku deployment with code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

i receive this error following after i deploy the nodejs server in heroku

2020-09-21T07:29:21.142276+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" ......

2020-09-21T07:29:21.697275+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" .......

I have added the engines{node,npm} in my package.json, and added MONGO_URI key in Config Vars in heroku dashboard since i use mongodv as my database. But i cannot open my website, it shows Application error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Heroku CLI and deploy the application again. Sometimes, when an invalid or a loophole is accessed, the application crashes. So, I suggest you to find the problem, fix it and deploy it back again.